# Update current cursor position record Sql

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have table with duplicate id record.I written a query to get all record with same id.Now i want to update record id such as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Student1
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO Student1
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1,0,4500, 'ram', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,2000, 'shyam', '05/09/2013'),
    (2,0,6500, 'radhe', '11/11/2014'),
    (2,0,8000, 'radheshyam', '15/11/2013'),
    (4,0,1500, 'ghanshyam', '08/11/2014')
;

id  status  amount  Name         date
1   0       4500    ram         04/02/2012
2   0       2000    shyam       05/09/2013
2   0       6500    radhe       11/11/2014
2   0       8000    radheshyam  15/11/2013
4   0       1500    ghanshyam   08/11/2014
```

SqlQuery:

```
SELECT * FROM Student1
   where id in (SELECT id FROM Student1 GROUP BY id HAVING count(*)>1)
```

Expected Result :

```
   id status    amount     Name        date
   2    0       2000      shyam      05/09/2013
   2    0       6500      radhe      11/11/2014
   2    0       8000    radheshyam   15/11/2013
```

Now i want to update any two records id's to 21,211.So i am trying to get the cursor count which will return 3.After getting count i m moving to position 2 to change its id but how to write query to update current cursor position record.

Comment: You can't use **multiple VALUES** lines **all at once** in the same INSERT statement. Instead, you have to run **multiple INSERTS**. One for each VALUES set.

Answer (score 0):

I din't test it, but this will get you going.

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while ( !cursor.isAfterLast()) {
   // update whatever you want here
   db.getWritableDatabase().update(
            //TABLE_NAME,
            //values,
            //whereclause,
            //args
    );
 cursor.moveToNext()
}
```

Get the values from the cursor on each position and make the updates. This operation should be done **outside the main thread**. You could use a asynctask.

But you shouldn't create DB records with ID duplication. Add a `AUTOINCREMENT` statement at you table creation.

Comment: Not getting your solution as i can get values of cursor at each position but i want to update current cursor position without using where clause

Comment: I suppose that you can't do that.

Comment: The cursor is created fetching DB entries. So, you'll need to change the DB entry. To do that you have to use some reference, hence the where clause.

Comment: I read you comment on the other answer. Tell me, are you merging 3 cursors? If so, you should mark the results of each cursor with a respective "type", so you can refer to that type and id, to change values on the db. When you change any of the 3 tables, merge the cursors again.
 I think your question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

No way to update the records in this way as there is no primary key field to use the where clause on. Always mark the id field as primary key to avoid such situations. The best you can do is find these entries, store the Date or name, which ever is unique, and then use that in the where clause to change the id.

```
do(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   //store the name or Date and call a method on the database
   // to update the entry to set new id where name equals to this name.

} while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Avoid such situations by marking the id field as primary key. SQLite auto-increments the primary key field even if it is not explicitly mentioned.

Comment: When you use the cursor, it is a copy of the table that you get back, which you can use to output the result. manipulating the cursor values, makes changes in the copy and not in the actual database. you have to make a separate update method to access and make changes to the database directly. It cannot be done through the cursor ofcourse.

Comment: All this entries are created by comparing 3 tables,so duplicate id means different record using same id so i have to first change them and then copy the whole table into new table which is having id as primary key.

Comment: There seems to be some design issues if that is the case. I'm sure you'll get a solution if you search this site meticulously. Try searching for joins and inner joins for better joining two tables and see how primary keys behave. But as of now, the best solution does seem to be creating a new table with id as primary key and then filling it up with the data from the other tables except for the id field. But there has to be a better way. Search for it. :)